# Can a failed Btrfs drive in RAID-1 be replaced live?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, btrfs

I am trying to decide on a filesystem and would like to know if it is possible to replace a failed drive in btrfs RAID without downtime.

1. Suppose I create a new btrfs filesystem using the command

   ```
   mkfs.btrfs -d raid1 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
   ```
2. Now suppose one day `/dev/sdc` fails. There are two possibilities: it can fail gradually, showing S.M.A.R.T. errors - in this situation I can add a new device with `btrfs device add /dev/sde /mnt; btrfs filesystem balance /mnt` and then remove the old one with `btrfs device delete /dev/sdc /mnt`.
3. But if it suddenly fails, becoming unreadable... A web search says in this situation I must first unmount the filesystem, mount in degraded mode, add a new device, then remove the missing device.

   ```
   umount /mnt
   mount -o degraded /dev/sdb /mnt
   btrfs device add /dev/sdf /mnt 
   btrfs device delete missing /mnt
   ```

An unmount is obviously a disruptive operation so there would be downtime - any application using  the filesystem would get an I/O error. But these kind of "tutorials" on btrfs look outdated, considering btrfs is under heavy development.

Question is: considering current state of btrfs, is it possible to do this online, i.e. without unmounting?

If not, there is a software-only solution that can fulfill this need?

Comment: If one drive catches fire, the rest of your system is probably on fire too

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Funny you.. :) I just wanted to make it very clear that I meant a catastrophic, sudden and unpredictable failure - the drive simply stops working. This is rather uncommon, hard disk usually fail gradually and with effective monitoring I can replace them before that happens, but what if...

Comment: In Linux 3.8 `btrfs replace mountpoint old_disk new_disk` was added.

Comment: @Brian woow... That is the answer. I googled for "btrfs replace" and this showed up http://lwn.net/Articles/524589/ . It is *_exactly_* what I was looking for. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Linux 3.8, `btrfs replace mountpoint old_disk new_disk` was added. If you're running a recent kernel, it will provide the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: This would now be `btrfs replace start /dev/old /dev/new /mountpoint` (**start** has been added). Also see `man btrfs-replace`.